# page child control

Tags: asp.net, controls

asp.net page is also a control.
how can I access child control within page control?

```
this.page.?
```

Comment: Recursive example provided in my answer below. Taken from here: http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/5127.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access it via the [Controls Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20zys56y.aspx)

```
Page.Controls
```

[Recursive FindControls from Rick Strahl's Blog](http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/5127.aspx)

```
public static Control FindControlRecursive(Control Root, string Id)
{
    if (Root.ID == Id)
        return Root;

    foreach (Control Ctl in Root.Controls)
    {
        Control FoundCtl = FindControlRecursive(Ctl, Id);
        if (FoundCtl != null)
            return FoundCtl;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Be careful with this however... This is not a method you want to be using inside a loop or anything.

Answer (score 5):

Try this :

```
Control childControl = Page.FindControl("YourControlsID");
```

Comment: Be careful with this method though because it is not recursive to child controls. You will need to be sure that the control your are looking for is actually a child of the page and not a child of a panel or some other child control within the page.

Comment: +1 and it might also be important to note that this will only work for first order child controls and their siblings. If you want to find nested controls, you would need to use recursion.

Comment: can you provide recursion code?
Does Page.Contorls contain first order children?

Answer (score 4):

- Page.Controls
- FindControl method